# Issue with removing images from PDF using pdf-lib in React project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am working on a React project where I have implemented a PDF processor using the pdf-lib library. The goal is to allow users to upload a PDF containing images, and then remove all the images from the PDF on the server side before providing a modified PDF for download. The front-end takes the URL of the PDF as input, sends it to a serverless function, and receives the processed PDF in response.

I have successfully set up the serverless function using Node.js and the pdf-lib library to process the PDF. However, when trying to remove images from the PDF, I encountered the following problem. When modified pdf downloaded, it's not opening. Just saying something like: "Could not open pdf".

Here is the relevant code snippet from the serverless function:

```
import { PDFDocument, StandardFonts, rgb } from 'pdf-lib';
import axios from 'axios';
import pdfParse from 'pdf-parse';

async function removeImagesFromPDF(pdfUrl) {
  try {
    // Fetch the PDF from the provided URL
    const response = await axios.get(pdfUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
    const pdfBytes = new Uint8Array(response.data); // Convert ArrayBuffer to Uint8Array

    // Parse the PDF to extract text content
    const pdfText = await parsePdfToString(pdfBytes);

    // Create a new PDF document with extracted text
    const textOnlyDoc = await PDFDocument.create();
    const textPage = textOnlyDoc.addPage([600, 400]);
    const font = await textOnlyDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica);
    textPage.drawText(pdfText, {
      x: 50,
      y: textPage.getHeight() - 50,
      size: 12,
      font: font,
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0),
    });

    // Save the modified PDF (text-only version)
    return textOnlyDoc.save();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing PDF:', error);
    throw new Error('Error processing PDF: ' + error.message);
  }
}

async function parsePdfToString(pdfBytes) {
  try {
    const pdfText = await pdfParse(pdfBytes);
    return pdfText.text;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error parsing PDF:', error);
    throw new Error('Error parsing PDF: ' + error.message);
  }
}


export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
    return;
  }

  const { pdfUrl } = req.body;
  if (!pdfUrl) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'PDF URL is missing in the request body' });
    return;
  }

  try {
    const processedPdfBytes = await removeImagesFromPDF(pdfUrl);

    // Send the processed PDF as the response
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="processed.pdf"');
    res.status(200).send(processedPdfBytes);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing PDF:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to process the PDF' });
  }
}
```

To provide context, here is my component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const PdfProcessor = () => {
  const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = useState('');
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false);
  console.log("I am PDF URL" + " " + pdfUrl)

  const handlePdfUrlChange = (event) => {
    setPdfUrl(event.target.value);
  };

  const handlePdfProcessing = () => {
    setProcessing(true);

    // Make a POST request to the serverless function
    fetch('/api/remove-images', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ pdfUrl }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to process the PDF');
        }
        return response.blob(); // Convert the response to a Blob
      })
      .then((blob) => {
        // Create a URL from the Blob to download the processed PDF
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Create a link element to trigger the download
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.download = 'processed.pdf';
        link.click();

        // Clean up the created URL
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        setProcessing(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error processing PDF:', error);
        setProcessing(false);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={pdfUrl} onChange={handlePdfUrlChange} />
      <button onClick={handlePdfProcessing} disabled={processing}>
        {processing ? 'Processing...' : 'Process PDF'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PdfProcessor;
```

I have researched this issue and attempted alternative approaches to remove images from the PDF, but I am still encountering the same error. Sorry for a mess in code, just trying to make it work.

I suspect that the issue might be related to the version of pdf-lib or possibly a mistake in my implementation of the PdfProcessor component.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully remove images from the PDF using pdf-lib in my React project.

Thank you for your help!